# How to mass export projects in Eclipse (zip align and sign)

Tags: android, eclipse, export, projects

I am looking for a way/a script that will allow me to mass export lots of Eclipse projects without my intervention. They must all be zip aligned and signed with my key, have my alias, everything that's needed for them to be uploaded.

Why do I need it? I have around 80 projects and it's a pain to constantly export them manually. I update them quite often.

One thing to note: the resulting apk must have the name of the project name (not the package name). I know it's something unusual but that's how I need it.

Does anyone know how to do this? Even if it's a paid method I'd be into it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would really depend on the build system that you are using, but more than likely a shell script would be your best bet. Have it run ant/maven/gradle and then rename/move and zip the files up.